# React fetch side effect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, rerender

My post is more of a question than a problem.
In react, in order to fetch data from an API we use the hook useEffect. But why not just work with states to manage the re-renderings ? (see example bellow)

```
import React from "react"

export default function App() {
    const [starWarsData, setStarWarsData] = React.useState({})
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = React.useState(false)

    if (!isLoaded) {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*50)
        fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${randomIndex}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setStarWarsData(data))
        setIsLoaded(true)
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(starWarsData, null, 2)}</pre>
            <button onClick={() => setIsLoaded(false)}>Load random charachter</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

As you can see, I manage the re-rendering with a simple if statement. Can you tell me why I should go with useEffect when fetching data and not the way presented above ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It stops right where you described, or earlier. If you don't have anything to clean up, you don't need that part. React also double renders in strict mode, so you'll get two instances where `isLoaded` is false in that case. Ultimately you're asking why you shouldn't use React as it's designed to be used, and it's unlikely that you'll find support for your decision

Comment: @BrianThompson it's not a decision for me to use react in other ways than how it's designed. It's a geniune question. I'm just trying to understand in dept the use of useEffect. But it looks like my question is in some way offensive. Anyways, thanks for the  comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I actually think it's a great question :)

Technically, what you are doing here will work, because you are making sure the fetch will occur only once and will not retrigger infinite renders.

But there are some flaws with performing side effects inside the render phase:

1. You are using useState inside the render phase, which means that you are in danger of re triggering the render phase infinitely.
2. Let's assume you would only want to fetch the data once after the mount phase has completed (useEffect with empty dependency array OR componentDidMount event in class components) - You could get rid of the isLoaded state and use only 1 state for storing the data, because the code will trigger only once, and you won't have to worry about re renders with the isLoaded state.
3. In every single render, you are going to check if isLoaded is false, which is redundant because we know exactly when we want to refetch data. (Only after mount, and after clicking on the 'Load random character' button)

By using **[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)** - you are making sure the data fetching will not interrupt the UI, and will not retrigger renders unwillingly by using an array of dependencies.
By using this hook, the code is cleaner, and you know exactly when it will be called.

(side note - remember that setState is asynchronous, which can lead into unexpected renders, and also to some issues if you rely on the previous value of that state)